# Keyboard navigation is not working correctly and the code is messy

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard

I'm using a script that uses the keyboard keys J & K to scroll between articles on my blog. The code right now is quite messy and has an error where it currently only works one time... I'm wondering if there is an easier way to use the J & K keys to scroll smoothly between posts, because this script is just so big and there has to be an easier way. This script is using the jQuery library and the scrollto.js. Basically, I'd like a different script that scrolls smoothly between posts when the J & K keys are pressed.

```
        window.viewport = { height: function() { return $(window).height(); }, width: function() { return $(window).width(); }, scrollTop: function() { return $(window).scrollTop(); }, scrollLeft: function() { return $(window).scrollLeft(); } }; $.belowthefold = function(element, settings) { var fold = $(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop(); return fold <= $(element).offset().top - settings.threshold; }; $.abovethetop = function(element, settings) { var top = $(window).scrollTop(); return top >= $(element).offset().top + $(element).height() - settings.threshold; }; $.rightofscreen = function(element, settings) { var fold = $(window).width() + $(window).scrollLeft(); return fold <= $(element).offset().left - settings.threshold; }; $.leftofscreen = function(element, settings) { var left = $(window).scrollLeft(); return left >= $(element).offset().left + $(element).width() - settings.threshold; }; $.inviewport = function(element, settings) { return !$.rightofscreen(element, settings) && !$.leftofscreen(element, settings) && !$.belowthefold(element, settings) && !$.abovethetop(element, settings); }; $.extend($.expr[':'], { "below-the-fold": function(a, i, m) { return $.belowthefold(a, {threshold : 0}); }, "above-the-top": function(a, i, m) { return $.abovethetop(a, {threshold : 0}); }, "left-of-screen": function(a, i, m) { return $.leftofscreen(a, {threshold : 0}); }, "right-of-screen": function(a, i, m) { return $.rightofscreen(a, {threshold : 0}); }, "in-viewport": function(a, i, m) { return $.inviewport(a, {threshold : 0}); } }); 


        $(document).keypress(function( event ) { 
        if(event.which === 106) { 
            var currPost = $('article:in-viewport').eq(0); 
            var target = $(currPost).next('article'); 

            $.scrollTo( $(target), {
                duration: 400, 
                axis: "y", 
                offset: -120
            }); 
        }

        else if(event.which === 107) { 
            var currPost = $('article:in-viewport').eq(0); 
            var target = $(currPost).prev('article'); 

            $.scrollTo( $(target), {
                duration: 400, 
                axis: "y",
                offset: -120
            }); 
        }

    });
```

Blog I'm using the script on - http://jtestblog1.tumblr.com/
EDIT: The offset -120 is so when it scrolls, it shows the entire article including the padding-top.

Answer (score 0):

Well 'code is messy' is not really acceptable for a Stack Overflow question. When something is messy that means you need to refactor it. Although it seems petty, the correct way to ask would be 'How could I refactor this code to keep it more DRY (don't repeat yourself)? Here's what I tried'.

Also, in the day of minifiers and gzip, code length should not be your concern - it should be code readability and reuse.

That being said, a switch is a common way to clean up keypress situations.

```
(function(){
  var position = null;
  $(window).keypress(function( e ) {
    var posts = $('article');

    // note, it would probably be more reliable to start `position` at 0
    // and just get rid of this selector, but this works.
    if(position == null){
      position = posts.find(':in-viewport').first().index();
    }

    var keys = {
      k: 106,
      j: 107
    };

    switch (e.which) {
      default:
      case keys['k']:
        position++;
        break;
      case keys['j']:
        position--;
        break;
    }

    // fixes looping.
    if(position == posts.length+1){
      position = 0;
    } else if (position == -1){
      position = posts.length;
    }

    var target = $(posts[position]);
    // Don't try to scroll on something that doesn't match.
    if( target.length > 0 ) {
      $.scrollTo(target, {  // target doesn't need to be wrapped twice, 
        duration: 400,      // it is already a $ object.
        axis: "y",
        offset: -120
      });
    } 
  });
})();
```